# religious tax exempt addresses in detroit/Michigan

Tags: geospatial, taxes

I am looking to obtain a full list of all religious institutions that are deemed tax exempt for Detroit Michigan. I have visited there website http://www.detroitmi.gov/ and could not find such a list. Before I file a FOIA request I was wondering if there some sort of database that compiles this information, form a state, county or municipal/city level